# Windows 7 File Copy / Backup

Tags: windows, backup

Does anyone how to copy files from one media (hard drive) to another external media (hard drive, flash drive etc) without changing the Date Created, Date Modified file attributes. When I copy Outlook Emails from one medium to the other, the date attributes change. I need them to remain unaltered when I copy from one medium to the next.
I copy files for backup purposes and would like the files copied only with their attributes unchanged.

Answer (score 2):

in CMD

```
robocopy SOURCE TARGET /mir /copyall
```

Run as administrator.

/mir made a mirror with folders and subfolders /copyall takes all content of u want to clone(copy timestamps) 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145.aspx

Comment: Could you explain this please? For example, what does `/mir` do?

Comment: /mir
made a mirror with folders and subfolders
/copyall
takes all content of u want to clone(copy timestamps)
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145.aspx

Comment: Great! Can you [edit] the answer and add that in please? It will make the answer much better!

Comment: Note that **/copy:dat** is the default so timestamps are copied anyway. **/dcopy:t** will copy dir filestamps as well if required.

Comment: You are absolutly right. that keep timestamps so which is the diference?, the diference the first option in my answer keep all filestamps, but your options works as well for sure :)

Comment: In terms of *file* timestamps there's no difference between **/copy:dat** (which is the default and doesn't need to be specified explicitly), and **/copyall**. As `robocopy /?` shows, **/copyall** is "equivalent to **/copy:datsou**", i.e. it adds **/copy:sou** to the default **/copy:dat**.

Comment: Keep two things in mind.  One is that robocopy was designed to copy folders.  If you run into problems with something not working correctly, confirm that your paths are good, and try to use folders as your source and target as much as possible.  Two is that there are a lot of options for robocopy, and that some of them can be used to remove files (like when synchronizing two folders).  Make a test folder structure with a few files and test your commands against it.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a tool called FastCopy, which maintains file attributes including date and modified, and also copies using a buffer, so it's fairly quick.

http://download.cnet.com/FastCopy/3000-2248_4-10905019.html

I've used that for a while now for large business copies, which require all the information to be exactly mirrored on another storage point.

Answer (score 0):

Use the built-in robocopy command line tool. It preserves filestamps so anything copied to another medium will retain the original date attributes.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145.aspx